# Getting " maximum number of DatagramSockets reached" issue while stop/start exisiting sparkcontext in databricks

Tags: java, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

[image]
Attached logs: (Facing this issue while stop/start the existing sparkcontext in databricks.Facing this issue while stop/start the existing sparkcontext in databricks. Need to enable spark default metrics in job level.

```
com.timgroup.statsd.StatsDClientException: Failed to start StatsD client
    at com.timgroup.statsd.NonBlockingStatsDClient.<init>(NonBlockingStatsDClient.java:95)
    at com.timgroup.statsd.NonBlockingStatsDClient.<init>(NonBlockingStatsDClient.java:64)
    at org.zignallabs.streaming.metrics.SerializableStatsDClient.readObject(SerializableStatsDClient.java:124)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor204.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1184)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2322)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2213)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1669)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2431)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2355)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2213)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1669)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:2119)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1657)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:2119)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1657)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2431)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2355)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2213)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1669)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:2119)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1657)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2431)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2355)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2213)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1669)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2431)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2355)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2213)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1669)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2431)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2355)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2213)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1669)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:503)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:461)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:527)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor157.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1184)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2322)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2213)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1669)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2431)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2355)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2213)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1669)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2431)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2355)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2213)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1669)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:503)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:461)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:527)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor157.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1184)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2322)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2213)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1669)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2431)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2355)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2213)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1669)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2431)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2355)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2213)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1669)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:503)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:461)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:129)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$2(ResultTask.scala:65)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$1(ResultTask.scala:65)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.$anonfun$run$4(Task.scala:137)
    at com.databricks.unity.EmptyHandle$.runWithAndClose(UCSHandle.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.$anonfun$run$1(Task.scala:137)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$13(Executor.scala:902)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1697)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:905)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:760)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: **maximum number of DatagramSockets reached**
    at sun.net.ResourceManager.beforeUdpCreate(ResourceManager.java:73)
    at sun.nio.ch.DatagramChannelImpl.<init>(DatagramChannelImpl.java:107)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorProviderImpl.openDatagramChannel(SelectorProviderImpl.java:42)
    at java.nio.channels.DatagramChannel.open(DatagramChannel.java:149)
    at com.timgroup.statsd.NonBlockingUdpSender.<init>(NonBlockingUdpSender.java:22)
    at com.timgroup.statsd.NonBlockingStatsDClient.<init>(NonBlockingStatsDClient.java:93)
    ... 95 more
```

Comment: why are you doing it this way?

Comment: I want to enable job-level metrics. So that under one cluster, I can have multiple jobs. Each of these would send metrics for a different purpose.